# to find inverse laplace transform of $f(s)=s\ln\left|\frac s{\sqrt{s^2+1}}\right|$

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, inverse-laplace, laplace-method

I tried the differential property of the Laplace transform to the logarithm component, then I tried the “multiplying by s” property, but the answer would be infinity. What do you think is the solution?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).